# Edit svg or psd with java

Tags: java, image, svg, photo, psd

I have an image (psd or svg file) I want to use it as template. As I will use it several times, The only thing I want to edit is 2 text layers in each time. Can I make java program that can edit these layers pro-grammatically, as the user will enter the 2 texts that he wants them to put in the two layers in the image?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SVGs are just text files, so it is pretty easy to work with them.  The simple solution would go something like this:

1. Put some placeholder text in your template SVG file where you want the new text to go.  For example:

   `<text x="100" y="50">###TEXT1###</text>`
2. Write a simple java program to read in your SVG template into memory.  Into a string will do if it isn't ridiculously large.
3. Do a search and replace on your placeholder strings

   svgFileTxt.replace("###TEXT1###", newText);
4. Save the file out.

Photoshop files are going to be quite a bit trickier.  It would be better to use Adobe Scripting for them.  http://www.adobe.com/devnet/photoshop/scripting.html